# How to get knit a RNW file from a function call and put it in a package?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, knitr, sweave

I want to use knitr/sweave to generate a report via a function call. I have a function which creates some plots and tables. I want to give an option in that function to generate a pdf report with those plots. This function will be part of an R package.

The way I approaches this was that I will port a rnw template with the package and whenever the pdf generation option is active, use that template and counter to generate the report. The problem with that is, I don't know where the user will install the package, so location of the rnw file will be a problem also can I pass input arguments to the knit function which can be used in the report?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are after `system.file`.

The `knitr` vignette for using [jQuery DataTables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/datatables.html) documents (and does) this.

Comment: system.file will get me the location of the file right? So I will have to copy that file into the current working directory and then knit it?